# How to multiply five tensors of different ranks (contravariant, covariant and mixed) in Mathematica?

Tags: tensors

How to compute the following multiplication of five different tensors of different ranks in *Mathematica*

```
Subscript[R, μνρσ] k^μ Subscript[E, i]^ν \k^ρ Subscript[E, j]^σ
```

Comment: Look at `TensorContract`